# Error: AWS Identity and Access Management user accounts cannot be used for Amazon Mechanical Turk

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I'm trying to to make a simple API call to the Amazon Mechanical Turk service.
The documentations and samples show I should have an AWS AccessKeyId and SecretAccessKey in the config file.
I created a new set and granted it a Power User permissions.

Yet, when I I call `client.CreateHIT` I get the error

> AWS.MechanicalTurk.UnacceptableIdentity: AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) user accounts cannot be used for Amazon Mechanical Turk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use your administrator account access keys you were provided with when you created your AWS account, not keys that you've created for an IAM user.

This [getting started guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkGettingStartedGuide/SetUp.html) might help you out. In the guide, Amazon states:

> **Important** Amazon Mechanical Turk does not use AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) credentials.

UPDATE: In December 2015, [AWS announced](http://mechanicalturk.typepad.com/blog/2015/12/introducing-mechanical-turk-api-support-for-iam-credentials.html) that IAM is now supported on MTurk.

Comment: Yes. It works. But the "Important" note tells you what NOT to use. Not what does work :(

Comment: If you login with your root account, you will be able to retrieve the working keys from [this page](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials). The keys will work if it is the root account. The keys will not work if it is an IAM user with created access keys.